# JavaScript: Write time from JSON time server and checksum into HTML page

Tags: javascript, json, time, checksum

I am trying to read the time from a JSON server (in seconds since 1970) and output it into an HTML page. I would also like to add a three digit checksum (ideally only capital letters) to it at the end. I looked around and found some code for the JSON part, but have 2 remaining questions:
1) How do I actually write out the time into the HTML (I tried using document.write() but I could not get it to work)
2) How to come up with a checksum?
Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
test
<script> 
function getTime(success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT',
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}

getTime(function(time){ //note that getMonth yields a value between 0 and 11
    var seconds = time.getTime()/1000;

    alert( 'GMT is ' + seconds); //alert() works, but document.write() does not?
});
</script>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added question: How would I need to modify my script if I wanted to use: http://www.timeapi.org/

Comment: you can't use doc.write from an asynchronous function. try doing a direct html injection. e.g. `doc.getEleByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = seconds` or whatever instead.

Comment: @MarcB Please post that as an answer.